# Resolving services with named parameters

Tags: autofac

I have the issue that resolving services registered with named parameters lead to wrong resolution:

The registration is like that:

```
builder.RegisterType<CviStaticCacheManager>()
            .As<ICacheManager>()
            .Named<ICacheManager>(STATIC_CACHE)
            .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<CviRequestCacheManager>()
            .As<ICacheManager>()
            .Named<ICacheManager>(REQUEST_CACHE)
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Everything's working fine if I resolve a service which is registered like that:

```
builder.RegisterType<PermissionService>().As<IPermissionService>()
            .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>(STATIC_CACHE))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

My problem is that I have some registration which I can't modify that resolves services like that (*I can't use ResolveKeyed/ResolveNamed!*):

```
var cm = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<ICacheManager>()
```

Now I always get an instance of CviStaticCacheManager - doesn't matter in which order I might register it.

I tried to fix this issue in a module - but then I get always CviRequestCacheManager:

```
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
            new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ICacheManager),
                    (p, i) => i.ResolveKeyed<ICacheManager>(REQUEST_CACHE))
            });
    }
```

I'm really frustrated and I'm looking for a solution. Maybe somebody can help me.

Best Regards
Jörg

Comment: What do you want ? you want to set `StaticCacheManager` as a default registration when you resolve non named `ICacheManager` ?

Comment: I want to set CviRequestCacheManager as the default one.

Comment: I tried changing the order on which the registration is made and it works fine. See this code sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/F6JiTH .

Comment: Yes. This is what I expected, too. But in my case it doesn't work. I can change the order and get always CviStaticCacheManager which is wrong.

Comment: But you simulated exactly my case. ;-)

Comment: So your question is "Why changing the order of registration doesn't change the resolved component ?" right ?

Comment: I found out that the order of the ComponentRegistry of my LifetimeScope is changing for some requests. I'm really confused. I checked it using LifetimeScope.Resolve<IEnumerably<ICacheManager>>().

Comment: Strange is that the wrong scope ("AutofacWebRequest") has a ParentLifetimeScope == null, the correct one is set to root.

Comment: I can show you a solution to overrides default component but it is kind of dirty. I think you have something else in your code that break the normal behavior of *Autofac*. Could you share a sample code that illustrate your problem ?

Comment: I found the issue. Look at my answer below. But I've no idea why this is affecting the order of the ComponentRegistry.

Answer (score 0):

after commenting

```
//app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
//app.UseAutofacMvc();
```

it suddenly works. 
I don't need owin integration at the moment - but I really have no idea why the order of registered components seems to be affected if I enable calling **app.UseAutofacMvc();**

Regards
Jörg